# If a polynomial has only real zeros then $a_{0}+a_{1}+\cdots+a_{n}\le\frac{(n+1)^n}{\binom{n}{s}(n-s)^{n-s}(s+1)^s}\cdot\max_{k}a_{k}$

Tags: inequality, polynomials

**Question:**

> For all real polynomials $P(x)=a_{0}+a_{1}x+\cdots+a_{n}x^n$ of degree $n$, with only real zeros,we have
>   $$a_{0}+a_{1}+\cdots+a_{n}\le\dfrac{(n+1)^n}{\binom{n}{s}(n-s)^{n-s}(s+1)^s}\cdot\max_{k}a_{k},s=\lfloor \dfrac{n}{2}\rfloor$$

[image]

```
This problem is from Mitrinovic D.S Analytic inequalities (Springer 1970) Page 217.
```

He says that this inequality is due to L. Moser, J. R. Pounder and J.D. Dixon, who gave this generalization.

But I can't find it. Can someone solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: See http://cms.math.ca/cmb/v5/cmb1962v05.0259-0263.pdf

Comment: Hello,In china,this PDF can't open it,Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Since it seems the PDF linked by Macavity is not accessible to everyone, I reproduce it here :

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]